# Не работает программа на Java. Не запускается остальная часть кода

Tags: java, строки, if, switch

Почему то не компилируется часть кода после System.out.println("Бот выбрал "+randS);
Программа завершается.

```java
    import java.util.*;

    public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Напиши одно из трёх: Камень, Ножницы, Бумага");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        String Check = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Игрок выбрал "+Check);

        List<String> game = new LinkedList<>();
        game.add("Камень");
        game.add("Ножницы");
        game.add("Бумага");

        Random random = new Random();
        int i = random.nextInt(3);
        String randS = game.get(i);
        System.out.println("Бот выбрал "+randS);

        if (Objects.equals(randS, Check))
            switch (Check) {
                case "Камень":
                    if (Check.equals(randS)) {
                        System.out.println("Ничья");
                    } else if (randS == "Бумага") {
                        System.out.println("Победил бот");
                    } else if (randS == "Ножницы") {
                        System.out.println("Победил игрок");
                    }
                    break;
                case "Бумага":
                    if (Check == randS) {
                        System.out.println("Ничья");
                    } else if (randS == "Ножницы") {
                        System.out.println("Победил бот");
                    } else if (randS == "Камень") {
                        System.out.println("Победил игрок");
                    }
                    break;
                case "Ножницы":
                    if (Check == randS) {
                        System.out.println("Ничья");
                    } else if (randS == "Камень") {
                        System.out.println("Победил бот");
                    } else if (randS == "Бумага") {
                        System.out.println("Победил игрок");
                    }
                    break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: уберите `if`, но оставьте `switch`

Comment: как написал Danis убери if, т.к. у тебя вероятность попасть в блок switch 1 к 3 (т.е. ты войдёшь в блок switch при условии, что обе переменные будут идентичны). Первый символ переменной должен быть в нижнем регистре,  замени Check на check, а в идеале название переменной должно отражать её содержимое, чтобы с первого взгляда было понятно что там хранится. например замени check на userInput или UserValue, что-то в этом роде...

Comment: вы когда-то слышали о том, что все объекты, включая String, можно сравнивать исключительно методом equals, а не == ?

Comment: Код прекрасно компилируется

Answer (score 0):

Как было указано, основная проблема -- с логикой программы, так как оператор switch выполняется *после проверки* что введённое значение пользователем и случайный выбор являются одинаковыми.  В принципе, после этого повторное сравнение в операторе `switch` вполне бессмысленно.  Также, строки положено сравнивать при помощи `String::equals/String::equalsIgnoreCase`.

Возможное решение: сначала проверить равенство введённого варианта и случайного выбора, если разные - определить победителя при помощи одной промежуточной булевой переменной.  Также здесь используется более лаконичная форма `switch expression` вместо привычного оператора:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Напиши одно из трёх: Камень, Ножницы, Бумага");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    String playerInput = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Игрок выбрал " + playerInput);

    List<String> game = new LinkedList<>();
    game.add("Камень");
    game.add("Ножницы");
    game.add("Бумага");

    Random random = new Random();
    String bot = game.get(random.nextInt(game.size()));
    System.out.println("Бот выбрал " + bot);

    if (Objects.equals(bot, playerInput)) {
        System.out.println("Ничья");
    } else {
        Boolean botWin = switch (playerInput) {
            case "Камень"  -> bot.equalsIgnoreCase("Бумага");
            case "Бумага"  -> bot.equalsIgnoreCase("Ножницы");
            case "Ножницы" -> bot.equalsIgnoreCase("Камень");
            default -> null;
        };
        if (null == botWin) {
            System.out.println("Неверный ввод: " + playerInput);
        } else if (botWin) {
            System.out.println("Выиграл бот!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Выиграл игрок!");
        }
    }
}
```